# Template specialization on a non template method in a template class

Tags: c++, template-specialization

It is possible to use template specialization to achieve stuff like this:

```
template <typename T>
T bar(T baz);

template <>
static unsigned int bar<unsigned int>(unsigned int baz)
{
    return baz + 1;
}

template <>
static int bar<int>(int baz)
{
    return baz + 2;
}
```

But what if the template parameters are on a class that contains the method?

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    T fooBar(T baz);
};
```

How can I (if at all) use template specialization to implement different forms of the fooBar method like I did above?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same basic way, you just have to make it clear where the template is.

**This would be wrong**, because while the method is implicitly a template (because the class is) it "inherits" the template types from the class:

```
template <>
inline unsigned int Foo::fooBar<unsigned int>(unsigned int baz)
```

So instead, specify the type after the class:

```
template <>
inline unsigned int Foo<unsigned int>::fooBar(unsigned int baz)
{
    return baz + 1;
}

template <>
inline int Foo<int>::fooBar(int baz)
{
    return baz + 2;
}
```

([Demo](http://ideone.com/8tN5eh))

Note that `inline` is required here since these are not template functions, but rather are specializations.  Therefore, they must follow the One Definition Rule.  `inline` suppresses the ODR as with any other non-template function/method definition.

Alternatively, you could declare them in the header and implement them in an implementation file:

```
// Header file
template <>
unsigned int Foo<unsigned int>::fooBar(unsigned int baz);

template <>
int Foo<int>::fooBar(int baz);

// Implementation file
template <>
unsigned int Foo<unsigned int>::fooBar(unsigned int baz)
{
    return baz + 1;
}

template <>
int Foo<int>::fooBar(int baz)
{
    return baz + 2;
}
```

The same basic syntax applies to template methods in template types, except you need two `template <>` since you are specializing two different levels of templates:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void foobar(T t, U u);
};

// Specialization of T=int, U=unsigned int
template <>
template <>
inline void Foo<int>::foobar<unsigned int>(int t, unsigned int u)
{
    // ...
}
```